# Executing Thread while dynamically updating UI

Tags: c#

I've been having the worst time trying to figure this out. I'm quite confused when it comes to threading.

What I'm trying to do is have a delay of 1 pause in the function and the continue the function until another 1 sec pause comes along and finally finish the function.

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // initalize splash screen
        DatabaseStatus(); // set database connection
        getUserInfo(); // get user information
        showInfo(); // show app information on splash screen
        System.Threading.Thread wa = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(checkUser));
        wa.IsBackground = true;
        wa.Start();
    }

    void checkUser()
    { 
        if (RegisteredUser)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Loading user settings...";  // SHOW THIS TEXT AND WAIT 1 SECOND UNTIL NEXT
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 

            if (DATABASE_CONNECTION)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += "Loging on...";
                // WAIT AGAIN 1 SEC AND CONTINUE///
                LoginCheck login = new LoginCheck(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
                if (login.LOGIN_SUCESS)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += "Sucess!";
                   // SHOW THIS TEXT AND WAIT 1 SEC UNTIL SPLASH SCREEN FADE OUT//
                    //MessageBox.Show(login.HASH);
                    opac.Interval = 12;
                    opac.Start();
                    opac.Tick += new EventHandler(dec);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(login.HASH);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Not user profile found...";
            // ask user to register
        }
    }
}
```

Where I've placed the comments is where I want the thread to pause and continue...

Anyone have any input?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=update%20ui%20background%20thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to do everything in a separate Background worker thread and update the status in the UI.  Which makes UI faster and ur application reliable.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: After playing around a bit and looking at the link you gave mem I finally got it to work!

Answer (score 2):

First, you must know when working with WinForms (and also WPF/Silverlight... right?) that you cannot, should not, manipulate UI elements from any other thread except the original that created the form/control.

If you need to do async work, you will need use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to transition your UI work back over to the form or control's thread. Also, consider using delegates (`MethodInvoker` is handy) rather than creating your own threads.

Also, you need to start your async work during or after the `Load` event, otherwise your logic will start to execute before the form is even displayed (see my example below).

I took your example and put it into a simplified sample of my own.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        RegisteredUser = true;
        DATABASE_CONNECTION = true;


    }

    private void UpdateStatus(string message)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => richTextBox1.Text += message));
    }

    private void CheckUser()
    {
        if (RegisteredUser)
        {
            UpdateStatus("Loading user settings..."); // SHOW THIS TEXT AND WAIT 1 SECOND UNTIL NEXT
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            if (DATABASE_CONNECTION)
            {
                UpdateStatus("Logging on...");
                //// WAIT AGAIN 1 SEC AND CONTINUE///
                //LoginCheck login = new LoginCheck(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
                if (true)//login.LOGIN_SUCESS)
                {
                    UpdateStatus("Success!");
                    // SHOW THIS TEXT AND WAIT 1 SEC UNTIL SPLASH SCREEN FADE OUT//
                    //MessageBox.Show(login.HASH);
                    //opac.Interval = 12;
                    //opac.Start();
                    //opac.Tick += new EventHandler(dec);
                }
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(login.HASH);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateStatus("No user profile found.");
            // ask user to register
        }
    }

    protected bool DATABASE_CONNECTION { get; set; }

    protected bool RegisteredUser { get; set; }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var invoker = new MethodInvoker(CheckUser);
        invoker.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use a method such as `UpdateStatus` to do work on the UI for me, ensuring its done on the UI thread. You can use any number of similar methods to do other stuff in the UI, such as trigger the fading of your form or whatever.

You shouldn't even show message boxes outside the UI thread; have those invoked safely by a similar method (also, for debugging, just `Debug.WriteLine` to write messages to the debugger rather than pop up message boxes all over).

Comment: Thanks for the input. However I'm still getting the issue where the logic is being done before the form ever shows. Normally the form takes almost 1 sec to fully load. With this method, the form takes 5 secs do load with the last UpdateStatus message. What I`m trying to do is create a splash screen and show status updates on in a textbox.

Comment: I will have to see your updated code. Perhaps you missed one of the changes I specified. The example I created does precisely what I explained.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Invoke()  see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2083/The-key-to-multi-threaded-Windows-Forms-UI-interac)

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{      
    bool DATABASE_CONNECTION;
    bool RegisteredUser; // if user has been registered
    string USER_NAME;
    string PASSWORD;
    double LIN_x = 0.01;

    DialogResult result;
    custom con = new custom();
    Timer opac = new Timer();

    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // initalize splash screen
        DatabaseStatus(); // set database connection
        getUserInfo(); // get user information
        showInfo(); // show app information on splash screen
    }

    private void UpdateStatus(string message)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => richTextBox1.Text += message + Environment.NewLine));
    }

    void checkUser()
    {
        UpdateStatus("Loading user settings..."); 
        if (RegisteredUser)
        {
            UpdateStatus("User " + USER_NAME + " found." );
            if (DATABASE_CONNECTION)
            {
                UpdateStatus("Logging on..."); 
                LoginCheck login = new LoginCheck(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
                if (login.LOGIN_SUCESS)
                {
                    UpdateStatus("Success! Loading " + con.AppTitle() + "...please wait");

                    //UpdateStatus(login.HASH); return hash string from web site
                    fadeSplash(); // begin fade out of form
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdateStatus("There was an error logging in."); 

                }
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateStatus("No database connection found."); 

            }
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateStatus("No user found"); 

            Reg(); // Registration form
        }
    }

    private void fadeSplash()
    {
        opac.Interval = 12;
        opac.Tick += new EventHandler(dec);
        opac.Start();
    }

    private void dec(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity -= LIN_x;
        if (this.Opacity < 0.04)
        {
            opac.Stop();
            this.Hide();
            main open = new main(); // start application
            open.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code where the fade method doesn't fire during MethodInvoke

Comment: You still have message boxes and forms being displayed from the non-UI thread. `BackgroundWorker` seems ill-suited for this task, because while you have at least one situation where you need halt execution in the async thread and prompt the user for input, and return that input back to the async thread and continue work. `BackgroundWorker` does not support this; you start work, fire off progress updates, and then an event at the end for when work is completed or cancelled. You need something that is more interactive, which is why I gave you the answer I did.

Comment: That was my bad. The reason it took so long is because I was working on another PC whose windows host did not resolve my private server properly and caused the DATABASE_CONNECTION bool to fail... I had to put a timeout.

Anyway, I re-tried your method, with a few minor tweaks, and it worked perfectly fine. My question is though, when should you use Invoke and when should you use a BackgroundWorker?

Also, how can I stop the thread? For example, I'd like it to stop if user not found and begin a prompt?

Thanks again

Comment: I would opt for `BackgroundWorker` if you can, since it's already done for you and easy enough to use. However, `BackgroundWorker` is only going to be useful for you if you only need the following 1. Start work async 2. Fire off progress notifications 3. Signal when work is done. As I stated in my previous comment, your work is more interactive, so `BackgroundWorker` doesn't quite fit the bill (but ALMOST does).

Comment: I'll agree with you on that and I've discarded the BackgroundWorker for this example and went with the MethodInvoker instead, which turned out more accurate. The only thing I found though is stopping this at some point. At the end of my function, I begin a Timer that fades my form away (when user logged in). It seems as though that Timer and the original thread clash and it doesn't fire like it's suppse to...  see code

Comment: If you use `Invoke` when signaling the UI thread, this should cause your worker thread to wait until `Invoke` returns. `BeginInvoke`, which you see in my example, fires off the message and continues without pausing the worker thread.

Comment: I do appologize for all these questions. It's been less than a week I'm working with C# and it's a big leap from PHP, so bared with me. I'm still not too familiar with the implementation of `Invoke` which is still quite confusing... If you say `BeginInvoke` fires without pausing, why wouldn't it continue to fire my function that starts a timer?